# Is the any way to simplify this code into less number of lines?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void input(int[] array){

}

public static void input(String[] array){

}

public static void input(double[] array){
        
}
```

As this is working fine I wanted to know is there any way to create a single function for all array data types. Can it apply to Array List?

Comment: You likely won't want to simplify it beyond what you have here. Simplifying objects is easy, you can use an interface and create classes that implement said interface with the definition of the concrete type in there. But, you're dealing with primitives as well (int, double). You need to have a REALLY good reason to introduce ambiguity by trying to simply this code. What is your reason?

Comment: If you look at [the Arrays class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html), you'll see that the authors have repeated method names over and over, with different argument types, just as you've done here.  This is the good and normal way of doing things, when you're dealing with primitives.  If you're dealing with `Object` types, of course, you can use generics, with a type parameter listed at the front of each method, but it looks like that's not what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use generics for this purpose.

1. Having the function as static member

   Implementation will looks like this,

   ```
   public class ClassName {
      public static <T> void input(T[] array){

      }
   }
   ```

   And while using it Java will automatically interpret type

   ```
   ClassName.input(new Integer[]{});
   ClassName.input(new String[]{});
   ClassName.input(new Double[]{});
   ```
2. Having the function as class member

   Implementation will looks like this,

   ```
   public class ClassName<T> {
       public void input(T[] array){

       }
   }
   ```

   And you can use it like using ArrayList

   ```
   new ClassName<Integer>().input(new Integer[]{});
   new ClassName<String>().input(new String[]{});
   new ClassName<Double>().input(new Double[]{});
   ```

And Java generics won't support primitive types (int), only works with class types (Integer)

Comment: It is possible to use a generic on just 1 method without having the generic on the entire class.

Comment: The syntax is `public static <T> void input(T[] array){`

Comment: Also note that generics do not support primitive types, so `int[]` cannot be used with a generic, but `Integer[]` can be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the boxing and unboxing of primitives, there isn't any GOOD way to make it shorter.  You technically could try something along the lines of this with Java 19 and `--enable-preview` :

```
    public static void input(Object array) {
        switch(array) {
            case int[] intArray -> {
                for (int i : intArray) {
                    // do something useful
                }
            }
            case double[] doubleArray -> {
                // do something useful
            }
            case String[] stringArray -> {
                // do something useful
            }
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument must be an array of type int[], String[], or double[].");
        }
    }
```

.. but then you are just manually doing what the Java language would do for you with the overloaded methods.